# In Munchkin, can someone who doesn't participate in a combat play cards that benefit a player who is fighting a monster?

Tags: munchkin

This situation happened in our friendly game where 2 players had feelings for each other and were keen on helping each other. Because we already had a house rule in play that limited the amount of times someone could offer their help, eventually they couldn't legally help each other. However, when a player A was fighting a monster, player B who was not in that combat, played "-5 to a Monster", thus making player A win. Player A was not on level 9, so the result wouldn't end the game, but I felt it was against the rules. However when they argued with me, I couldn't find anything in the rules that would explicitly say Munchkins can't help each other outside of combat. Any words about "the competitive spirit" wouldn't matter to them.

Comment: I doubt what they are doing is against the rule, but Munchkin is much more flexible than you think. If that two players are always helping each other you can always form another "Party" with another player which you agree to help each other and collectively sabotage these two players. I can't say if such a move will cause any relationship issues out of the game, but it certainly will rebalance the game. In fact, in most games I played, if two players are helping each other too much they'd end up being targeted by all the others since they have the advantage of a permanent ally.

Answer (score 13):

### You can absolutely play cards to help other players, even when not involved in combat

From the [rules](https://munchkin.game/site-munchkin/assets/files/1138/munchkin_rules.pdf) (direct PDF link)

> You can interfere with others’ combats in several ways, including:
>
> *Use a one-shot card*. **You could help another player by using a
>   one-shot to strengthen his side.** Of course, you can “accidentally”
>   strengthen the monster with it, instead . . .

Emphasis mine